# Error when running flutter app on mac emulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am running into an error when trying to run my flutter app on my mac. I already added the entry "using UTF-8 encoding. 
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile: 
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 " into the ~profile file but it still doesn't run. here is the debug console output:

[!] Unable to determine Swift version for the following pods: 
- `device_calendar` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`Runner`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod. 
- `flutter_email_sender` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`Runner`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod. 
- `flutter_sms` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`Runner`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod. 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:125:in `verify_swift_pods_swift_version' 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:39:in`validate!' 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:590:in `validate_targets' 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:158:in`install!' 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run' 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in`run' 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in`' 
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load' 
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in`' 
Error output from CocoaPods: 
↳ 
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding. 
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile: 
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
Error running pod install Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ. 
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0):

Open the podfile in ios folder. You can set the Swift version by including e.g. `ENV['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3'` at the top of your Podfile.

Comment: I added that line. Now it hangs on launching

Comment: No error. Looks like there was a hot fix yesterday for XCODE 10.  I updated to 11.3 XCODE but it still hangs with no error message. I cannot run flutter doctor, makes zero sense